# Django - putting HTML tags inside blocks of text subject to translation

Tags: django, translation

I am translating my web site from English into Russian (using Django 1.9) and have screened the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans) several times, and I still can't solve the issue

I have the following snippet in my template:

```
{% blocktrans %}
     I have <strong>{{apple_count}}</strong> apples
{% endblocktrans %}
```

After running `makemessages`, my `.po` file looks like this:

```
msgid "I have <strong>%(apple_count)d</strong> apples"
msgstr "У меня есть %(apple_count)d яблок"
```

The problem is that after running the `compilemessages` command, the phrase stays in English in Russian version of the web site (in other words, the phrase is not translated into Russian). Please note that **the problem lies in `<strong>` tag. If I remove it from the template, all works just fine**. 
I've also tried to remove `<strong>` from the .po automatically-generated msgid so that the .po file would like this:

```
msgid "I have %(apple_count)d apples"
msgstr "У меня есть %(apple_count)d яблок"
```

...but this does not help either.

Does Django provide a way to include HTML tags in translation phrases? And if not, what is the cleanest work-around ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Django provide a way to include HTML tags in translation phrases? And if not, what is the cleanest work-around ?

The way to do it is exactly as you did it. It's totally fine to occasionally have some markup inside your `blocktrans` blocks.

I don't know why it doesn't work with your `<strong>` tag.I tested this on my django playground and it perfectly worked even with the markup included. The issue must be something else.

That's what the [gettext documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Preparing-Strings.html) says about this:

> HTML markup, however, is common enough that it’s probably ok to use in
>   translatable strings. But please bear in mind that the GNU gettext
>   tools don’t verify that the translations are well-formed HTML.